# VBA Textbox Autofilter hides everything

Tags: excel, vba, activex, autofilter

I implemented a google like search box into my spreadsheet, using an activex textbox.. However, in the beginning it worked fine, but now it hides the whole used range and i only see blank cells. This really needs to work 100%, but i can't figure out what's the problem.

The code is as follows:

```
Sub TextBox1_Change()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Range("$O$7").AutoFilter Field:=14, Criteria1:=TextBox1

End Sub
```

I'd appreciate your help with this issue.

Answer (score 0):

```
If TextBox1.vlaue = "" Then Application.Autofiltermode= False
```

Comment: Please not only post code, but explain what that code does.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any statement to clear previous filters, for example:
`Worksheets(1).AutoFilterMode = False`

Also, there should be `Application.ScreenUpdating = True`  before `End Sub` to restore screen updating.

Comment: I currently use a clear button for that. So, i make sure there is no filter before trying, but it still doesn't work. I also added Application.ScreenUpdating = True. No difference.

Comment: Are you sure that correct range and field index are specified in macro? Maybe recording a macro where you filter the list manually would give you a hint on what is wrong with the code.

Comment: thanks man, It was indeed the field index. Didn't think about that.